# Developing and Debugging Selenium tests on a cloud IDE

Tags: selenium-webdriver, preview

Is there a cloud IDE such as cloud9, or visual studio code that allows me to not only develop Selenium Scripts, but also debug and run the tests while the browser is visible?

Perhaps this could be achieved having a live preview of the execution, like it's done while developing websites.